# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Listener must implement EventListener

Tags: java, discord-jda

I tried to make a simple bot command which checks if the bot is working, and I encountered with the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Listener must implement EventListener
```

Here is my bot main code:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Activity;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.GenericMessageEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.interactions.commands.build.Commands;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class YoxMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("token here")
                .setActivity(Activity.watching("the server"))
                .addEventListeners(new Commands())
                .build();

    }

}
```

Test command code:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class testcommand extends ListenerAdapter {
    public void onMessageReceived(net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        if (event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase("!test")) {
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("Test").queue();
        }
    }

}
```

I searched for answers in the internet, and none really helped me.

Comment: Java naming convention says you should start class names with upper-case letters .... change testcommand to TestCommand so that it's easier to read.   Usually variables (instance objects) & functions start with lower-case letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you added `new Commands()` as your event listener. Your class is called `testcommand` so you have to do `addEventListeners(new testcommand())`. `Commands` is a class provided by JDA and used for the creation of [application commands](https://jda.wiki/using-jda/interactions/#command-interactions).